# Excel generate in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, excel, exception

I need to generate excel in .net and uploading same .
While creating excel it generates excel in html format and while uploading the excel it shows external table is not in format.
please suggest me how to create excel in .net and upload the same in .net

Comment: Try to find on internet. You will get plenty of examples and libraries to do that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just a quick search on google and you can probably solve half if not the entire task/issue you have.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that here on SO we have some guidelines and "rules" for questions. It would be nice if you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [how to ask a good question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), your question, in this state, is most likely to get closed due to lack of efforts from your side. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get the help you need.